# fastlane - detect host operating system

Tags: android, macos, fastlane

I want to detect host operating system on which `fastlane` is installed. I require this because, in my scripts, I have some commands that executes only on Mac while some executes only on Windows machines.

A small workaround I made is to create separate script files for mac and windows.

Consider the below code snippet, which is written in my Fastfile:

```
platform :android do
    desc "Client Release"
    lane :clientrelease do |options|
        sh "bash fastlane_script_mac.sh " + options[:bundleId] + " " + "release"
        gradle(
            task: "clean"
        )
        gradle(
            task: "assemble",
            flavor: "client",
            build_type: "release"
        )
    end
end
```

I am expecting something like below:

```
platform :android do
    desc "Client Release"
    lane :clientrelease do |options|
        if(OS == "MAC") {
            sh "bash fastlane_script_mac.sh " + options[:bundleId] + " " + "release"
        } else {
           sh "bash fastlane_script_windows.sh " + options[:bundleId] + " " + "release"
        }
        gradle(
            task: "clean"
        )
        gradle(
            task: "assemble",
            flavor: "client",
            build_type: "release"
        )
    end
end
```

If host operating system is windows, then use `fastlane_script_windows.sh` else use `fastlane_script_mac.sh`

Can someone please help me out with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastlane's `Helper` class has a few methods that can help you:

- `FastlaneCore::Helper.operating_system` returns a string: `"macOS"`, `"Windows"`, `"Linux"`, or `"Unknown"`
- `FastlaneCore::Helper.windows?` returns `true` or `false`

  - Similarly, you can use `FastlaneCore::Helper.linux?` or `FastlaneCore::Helper.mac?`